# VS2010 Crystal report data is not refresing on loading

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports, report

I am using Visual studio 2010 and crystal report to print data. While loading i noticed that first time uploaded data is coming every time if i reload this report. I tried to refresh the report with given Query.

'crystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();'
But this also not impacting in my output. every time i am getting same result what i received at first time loading.

Please suggest.

Comment: can you show us some code in order to suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Change:

from

```
crystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

to

```
crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```